# shared resource in a micro service architecture

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a spring boot service deploy in aws multiple server instance. ELB is use to load balance those service instance.

I need to have a global java map which is common to (access by) all service?

Is it possible to achieve similar?

Comment: I would suggest looking into Redis

Comment: How would you share a java map over different VMs ... I second Mark or use some other DB.

Comment: exactly. so in this kind of situation, that would be the only option know? thanks

Comment: The quickest to implement and safest to use. You could as well put effort into some remote object thingy ... but looking up shared data from different clients - that sounds like a db just naturally. And it gives you many positive sideeffects like ability to make snapshots, backups, use transactions ...